# How to call web service inside of forloop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

How do I call a web service inside a `for` loop? I have two web services. First I call one web service and that returns some data (name, userid, etc.). I use this userid to call the next service. I want to show all datas of camels in one scroll (for example two camels each have so many photos and videos), and I want to list all images and videos inside of the new scroll view.

My code am showing you below:

```
-(void)listiingNewCamels
{
    int numberOfCamels = [msgArray count];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCamels; i++)
    {
        camObject=(IZCamelObject *)[msgArray objectAtIndex:i];
        CGFloat yOrigin = i * 395;
        UIView*mySampleview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(34,yOrigin+20,702,365)];
        mySamplev.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        camelIDStr=camObject.CamelID;

        UIScrollView *myCamelImagesScroll=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(34,30,640,180)];
        myCamelImagesScroll.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
        [mySampleview addSubview:myCamelImagesScroll];
        [_camelListingScrol mySampleview];
    }
    _camelListingScrol.contentSize = CGSizeMake(395, numberOfCamels * 400);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web service calls could potentially take a few seconds for each call to complete, or even longer if the connection is slow or the server doesn't respond immediately.

You cannot combine GUI code and synchronous code that is slow together, for example suppose your for loop is like this in pseudo code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCamels; i++)
{
    get camel info from camObject
    make synchronous web service call 1
    make synchronous web service call 2
    create scroll view
 }
```

Suppose each web service call takes 2 seconds, and you have 10 camels that means it will take 20 seconds for the for loop to finish. Your app GUI will hang for 20 seconds and the user will not be able to use it.

You therefore have to make your web service calls asynchronous, and you also have to decide how you are going to design your program accordingly.

How you do that is up to you, one thing you could do is to draw your scroll view immediately with what camel information you have within IZCamelObject, and as each web service call finishes then update the scroll view.

Or when the app launches your model (do you know MVC?) immediately starts to make the web service calls, so that when your GUI scroll view calls the model for the camel data it has already (or most of it has) downloaded.

Your way of thinking, and therefore the design of your program, needs to change from synchronous to asynchronous. You need to first decide how you will deal with asynchronous data downloads before finding a solution.

GUI code should not make web service calls, that should be the responsibility of the model component, but to illustrate the concept of updating the scroll view in an asynchronous way it might look like this in pseudo code:

```
   create scroll view
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCamels; i++)
    {
        get camel info from camObject
        add a subview with info from camObject
        make asynchronous web service call 1 with completion block: {update subview with data from web service call 1}
        make asynchronous web service call 2 with completion block: {update subview with data from web service call 2
     }
```